# How to run AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS on Codecademy, the problem I have is when I transfer examples to my local machine I just get the controller name output, e.g. {{test}}, instead of "Hello World".

My script is very simple, index.html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body ng-contoller="MyCtrl">
    {{test}}
    <script src="amgular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:-

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope){
$scope.test = "Hello World";
}]);
```

What do I need to do to get a simple app to run locally.
I have followed the tutorial on AngularJS.org and can get their example to run on the local host, but when I shoehorn my code into their structure I still get {{test}}.

Comment: And errors are likely being thrown in browser console. Knowing what those errors are is first line of troubleshooting

Comment: Why did you rename angular.min.js to amgular.min.js ? is that a typo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a typo in your `script` tag, where you wrote `amgular.min.js` instead of `angular.min.js`.

Comment: Thank you.  I was data blind and now can't see from the egg on my face.

Comment: @IanThompson At least accept the answer if he solved it for you.